# Creating a Trigger that will create a new Opportunity Owner every time a there is a new Opportunity in Salesforce

Tags: triggers, salesforce

I'm new to Salesforce and I'm trying to create a trigger that will basically update fields and create a new Opportunity owner every time a new Opportunity gets added.

For clarity, I've attached my code below:

```
 trigger trig_Opportunity_CreateOppOwner on Opportunity (before insert, before update) {
     //Opportunity OppOwner = null;
     List<id>OppsID = new List<id>(); //Get the id of all new Opportunities owners

     for (Opportunity Opp : Trigger.new) { //If a new Opportunity is added, then create new OppOwner, if not, then don't add.
         OppsId.add(Opp.ID); //adds all new Opportunities Id's
     }

     List<Opportunity>OppToUpdate = [SELECT Id,
                                            Name,
                                            Owner__c,
                                            OppOwner,
                                     FROM Opportunity
                                     WHERE Id IN: Opp.ID // Select Id, OpportunityName,
                                    ];

     if Trigger.oldMap.get(opp.id).Owner__c != Trigger.oldMap.get(OppToUpdate.id).Owner__c // verify that if previous Opportunity has a matching owner.
        OppsId.add(Opp.ID); //populates new oppowner with ID's of all owners.
```

This is basically what I'm trying to do:
Trigger(Before Update, Before Insert){

1. Get all Triggered Opportunities.
2. Verify if old opportunities already has a matching Owner.
3. If it's not a matching owner, update Opportunity fields and update the opportunity.

I'm not sure how to get from step 2 to step 3. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

By the code that you provided isn't clear where it's finished, from my side seems that after couples of lines that you've provided another couples of lines exists. Could you please post all your code? If it isn't so, and code that you posted is all your code, from my point of view, this code do nothing, absolutely nothing.

Why?

- no validation's errors
- no DML operation

  ```
     trigger trig_Opportunity_CreateOppOwner on Opportunity (before insert, before update) {
   //Opportunity OppOwner = null;
  /* 
       List<id>OppsID = new List<id>(); //Get the id of all new Opportunities owners
       for (Opportunity Opp : Trigger.new) { //If a new Opportunity is added, then    create new OppOwner, if not, then don't add.
           OppsId.add(Opp.ID); //adds all new Opportunities Id's
       }
  */
       // 3 started lines might be replaced by the following one
       List<id>OppsID = Trigger.newMap.getKeys();
      //but the following code perform select on Opportunity object and return the same list as Trigger.new
      // OppToUpdate == Trigger.new 
      // What for? May be you should work with this part on "after insert/update"
       List<Opportunity>OppToUpdate = [SELECT Id,
                                          Name,
                                          Owner__c,
                                          OppOwner,
                                   FROM Opportunity
                                   //WHERE Id IN: Opp.ID // Opp - isn't exist and it  isn't list/set of id
                                   WHERE Id IN OppsId // I guess you meant this
                                  ];
       // 1.variable "opp" isn't exist here
       // 2. "OppToUpdate.id" - you can't use list in this manner
       if Trigger.oldMap.get(opp.id).Owner__c != Trigger.oldMap.get(OppToUpdate.id).Owner__c // verify that if previous Opportunity has a matching owner.
      OppsId.add(Opp.ID); //populates new oppowner with ID's of all owners.
  ```

Comment: The trigger runs in before context, which is run on your records in memory before they are commited to the database. All changes to the records on which your trigger is running (Opportunity in this case) will be modefied without the need to do an DML statement.  Your other comments are right however.

Comment: I mean DML on other objects, like an activity, account, contact, etc.